# How to avoid this overlapping?

Tags: android

I have an ListView in an Activity which is defined `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

This is the XML on each line of the ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/appname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textColor="#0000EE"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/contentedit" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edit"
    android:src="@drawable/contentdiscard" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I get this horrible **overlapping of the text with the icons, when the text is a bit longer.**

[image]

Please how can I fix it?

Comment: If you want to keep the relative layout, Just add toRightOf="@+id/id of the delete icon" to the textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#0000EE" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/contentedit" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edit"
    android:src="@drawable/contentdiscard" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinearLayout` with weights and the attributes `ellipsize` & `lines` as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#0000EE" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/contentedit" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/contentdiscard" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Smaller text would work.  So would smaller icons. You might also allow your text to wrap to multiple lines and increase the height of each item. One other thing you might try is to set ellipsize on the text views - anything to large gets cropped with a "..." placed on the end.

You could also remove the delete/edit icons and use a context menu - select a site and THEN make the icons appear

There are only so many ways to fit a lot of content on a small screen.